# Create a dictionary from lists which are created based on subsets of data

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dataset from which I am selecting each column as given in var and then calling an R function to calculate a metric.
While generating the lower the power is varied through mc_adj and various values for the mc_adj and lower are printed and the correspoding
values stored in separate lists.

```
var = ['Siver','cent','Multiplex']
#Medcouple:
#mc = medcouple_1d(y)
for k,v in enumerate(var):

    # use medcouple from mrfDepth (R) for now:

    y = np.array(final_data[v])
    mc = use_r_medcouple(y)
    # Evaluate lower bound based on mc:-
    iqr_x = iqr(y)
    q1 = np.percentile(y,25)
    # Pass the power as a parameter :
    mc_adj = range(1,25)
    power = []
    cutoff = []
    params = {}

    for i in mc_adj:
        # Generate lower for various values of power - to determine optimal cutoff.
        if (mc > 0):
            lower= q1 - 1.5*np.power(e,-mc_adj[i-1]*mc)*iqr_x
        else:
            lower = q1 - 1.5*np.power(e,-mc_adj[i-1]*mc)*iqr_x
        print (mc_adj[i-1],lower)
        #Output
        #1 -0.5159729533251924
        #2 -0.2867442303545527
        #3 -0.13645482753920707
        # cutoff should contain only from here
        #4 0.0379204715218498
        #5 0.02668168361269674
        #6 0.06903684395182615

        power.append(mc_adj[i-1])
        cutoff.append(lower)
```

I want to subset cutoff to contain only values greater than 0 and create a dictionary with each var as key and corresponding list as values.

```
'Siver' :'[0.7064935843796287, 1.325222704596175, 1.7503065451918585]'
'cent':'[0.0379204715218498, 0.02668168361269674, 0.06903684395182615]'
```

Below is a sample data:

```
    Siver   Multiplex   cent
52.47   76.38       78.72
45.36   07.65       76.68
14.93   0           58.83
9.67    0           51.47
37.98   35.69       17.48
1.88    124.28      43.79
3.77    130.50      59.27
0       9.90        63.05
```

Can someone please help me with this??

Comment: `if lower > 0: cutoff.append(lower)`?

Comment: your bit `if mc > 0: ...` - that seems to _always_ save the same thing to lower does it? Both the `if` and `else` seem to have the same formula. And they always get appended to cutoff? Also, do you need `mc_adj` as a variable, wouldn't `for i in range(24): ...` and just access `i`?